# Python Beautifulsoup find unique links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using `BeautifulSoup4` in `Python2.7` to try to find all unique links in an HTML body.

So if the HTML body has 3 of the exact same link, then only use one of them.

My code looks like this:

```
def extract_links_from_content(self):
    content = "%s %s" % (self.html_body, self.plaintext)
    url_regex = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
    links = []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")

    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        if not link.get('no_track'):
            target = link.get('href')
            name = link.get('data-name')
            link_text = unicode(link)

            # If there is no target or a mailto link
            # skip it, cause we can't track whats not there or an email link
            if not target or target.startswith('mailto') or '{' in target:
                continue

            # If the target is a bookmark, skip it
            if target.startswith('#'):
                continue

            target = re.search(url_regex, target)

            if target:
                links.append({
                    'name': name,
                    'target': target.group()
                })

    return links
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually combine all of the checks into a function and pass this function as a keyword `href` argument value to `find_all()`. Looks cleaner and more readable:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def filter_links(link):
    href = link and link.get('href')

    return all([
        link,
        link.name == 'a',
        href,
        not link.has_attr('no_track'),
        not href.startswith('mailto'),
        '{' not in target,
        not href.startswith('#')
    ])

content = "%s %s" % (self.html_body, self.plaintext)
pattern = re.compile(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")

links = []
for link in soup.find_all(filter_links):
    target = link['href']
    name = link.get('data-name')

    target = pattern.search(target)
    if target:
        links.add({
            'name': name,
            'target': target.group()
        })
```

To avoid duplicate links you can **make a set** out of the `links` list. For this to work, you would need to store *tuples* instead of dictionaries:

```
links.add((name, target.group()))
```

Comment: Here is my updated code: https://gist.github.com/dennismonsewicz/a1bba896d014ea1d49b8 but I am now getting the error `'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: @dennismonsewicz fixed, please try it out again.

Comment: @alexce how would I make a set out of the links list to avoid dupes?

Comment: @dennismonsewicz it's just `set(links)`.

Comment: @dennismonsewicz correct, you would need to have tuples in the list instead of dictionaries, updated the answer.